# Some strange shipout behaviors (plain tex)

Tags: margins, plain-tex, output-routine

I was trying to understanding how the size of a page is determined in terms of TeX primitives. As first attempt, I've tried to occupy completely the page with a simple header (a line) , a footer (in form of a big T) and centralized text content. But I've failed in this mission (**"You lose!"**). Please, take a look in my code.

```
 % initial configuration
\voffset=-1in
\hoffset=-1in
\hsize=10em
\vsize=10em

% defining layout page (at least, trying it)
\output{%
    \shipout\vbox{% this layout was uncaple to eliminate all margins! Bottom and right margins persist
    \leftskip=0pt
    \rightskip=0pt
    \hrule height 0pt depth 7pt
    \vfill
    \box255
    \vfil
    \hrule height 7pt depth 0pt
    \hbox to \hsize{\hfil\vrule height 70pt \hfil}}}

% hyphining at will (or almost this)
\pretolerance=45
\tolerance=10000

% local defintions
\def\correction#1{%
            \ifcase#1
                \moveright
          \or \moveright-
          \or \moveleft
          \or \moveleft-
            \or \kern % this generates a disaster! It's reasonable, but I haven't got it
            \or \kern-
            \else
                    \def\eliminatehsize##1{}
                    \expandafter\eliminatehsize\fi}

\def\arg{4} % in this cases, leads to \kern

% finally, text content of page
\vfil

\noindent Umas verdades quar seram tambem \vadjust{\correction\arg\hsize\vbox to 0pt{\hbox to 0pt {\vbox{\hsize=7em\noindent Mulambo Silvestre}}}} semper que tardia nostrum vitae moscaribatus.
\vfil
\penalty-10000 
\end
```

It could looks ungly at first but it's really simple. So... questions are:

**1)** Why there are a right and a bottom margin in the output? (I'm usingbTeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) and displaying dvi files with evince)

**2)** Why the box255 was not centralized?

**3)** Why a weird output (creating new pages!!!) when \arg values 4 (a kern is used as \correction). I hope it was lost only part of the content, the same as in \arg = 5 or \arg = 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Changing `\hsize` and `\vsize` only changes the size of the text block, not the physical page.  For DVI output, try adding `\special{papersize=\the\hsize,\the\vsize}` after setting `\hsize` and `\vsize`.

Comment: your kern is adding a vertical offset of `\hsize`  which seems odd thing to do but you don't say what you want it to do. The right and bottom margins are not specificable in plain tex, they are just teh space between what you print and the edge of whatever page size you print on.

Comment: I want only to investigate how page is determined by TeX primitives.

Comment: \special{papersize=\the\hsize,\the\vsize}. Is this a command that is processed by dvi or another driver? In other words, is it specific to which platform/driver?

Answer (score 2):

ad 1) there is no TeX primitives which controls page size when dvi output is used. The page size is set by configuration of pdf viewer or using an obscure \special. Dvi is old format which does not include the information about page sizes.

ad 2) box255 is not vertically centralized because there is only one line in it and the \vsize is set to 10em. Then smoething like `\setbox255=\vbox to10em{single line}` is internally processed, the box255 has its height 10em and the single line is here at the top (with `underfull \vbox`, but message about it is not appended).

ad 3) the \vadjust inserts vertical material: the `\kern\hsize` followed by a `\vbox`. This is much more than given `\vsize`, so first line (without `\vadjust`) is pocessed as first page (with `underfull \vbox`), second line (with a big `\vadjust`) is processed as second page (with `overfull \vbox`).

I don't know what is your intend but I know that things can be done more simple.

Comment: I want only to investigate how aspects of a page is determined by some TeX primitives, including in a case of a disaster. This was my intention.

Comment: ad 1) All right!

ad 2) But even if I change the size of the shippped out box, increasing its length, the box keeps anchored at the begin of the internal space.

ad 3) I comprehend it partially. Do you know a reference for this specific topic, preferentially excluding The TeXbook?

Comment: additionally to the comment about "ad 2" (about box centralization), when the size of the box is too much large, the box lefts the top-left corner. In some cases, gets a apparent centralizes position. In others (for larger \vsize), gets a lower position, creating to me a more strange scenario. Oh, Gods! PS: I am considering a "normalized" output, using reasonable values to \arg.

Comment: I don't understand what is your intend. You are experimenting with very extreme cases of TeX page breaking algorithms: underfull, overfull. The material is: one line, break point, big couple of boxes (they are bigger than \vsize), breakpoint. So, we cannot be surprise that we get extreme results with these extreme experiments. Your intend with \arg is understandable for me, I traced only one value \arg=4 (because this is i your code) and this makes the overfull at page two (via \vadjust).